# Javascript: What is the difference between _.sortBy and arr.sort?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to implement my own version of [_.sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) but I can't figure out the difference between _.sortBy and the sort that is builtin to Javascript Array instances. They seem to evaluate optional callback arguments differently. I am not sure why and how they evaluate callback arguments differently. Example:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
_.sortBy(arr, function(num){ return Math.sin(num); });
>>>[5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2]
arr.sort(function(num){ return Math.sin(num);})
>>>[4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1]
```

All my searching for things in regards to this topic renders results in the category of databases. I could not find this answer on google or SO. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

-Chopper Draw Lion4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_.sortBy` takes a function that *returns the value to sort by.*
`Array.sort` takes a *comparison function* instead.

The difference being that the callback function in `_.sortBy` just tells `sortBy` which value to sort by (hence the name). While with `sort`, the callback function takes *two* arguments and returns to `sort` which of these values was greater. Your use of `sort` is actually incorrect, this is how you're supposed to use it:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0; })
```